# Solving using DPLL sat solver

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, logic, first-order-logic, sat-solvers

I found a sat solver in

http://code.google.com/p/aima-java/

I tried the following code to solve an expression using dpllsolver

the input is

```
(A <=> B) AND (C => D) AND (A AND C) AND (NOT (B AND D)) AND (NOT (B AND D AND E))
```

CNF transformer transforms it to

```
 (  (  ( NOT A )  OR B ) AND  (  ( NOT B )  OR A ) )
```

it doesn't consider the other parts of the logic, it considers only first term, how to make it work correctly?

please suggest me if some other sat solver can do it

```
PEParser parser = new PEParser();
CNFTransformer transformer=new CNFTransformer();
Sentence and;
Sentence transformedAnd;
DPLL dpll = new DPLL();

Sentence sentence = (Sentence) parser.parse("(A <=> B) AND (C => D) AND (A AND C) AND (NOT (B AND D)) AND (NOT (B AND D AND E))");
transformedAnd = transformer.transform(sentence);

System.out.println(transformedAnd.toString());
boolean satisfiable = dpll.dpllSatisfiable(transformedAnd);

System.out.println(satisfiable);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one out: http://www.sat4j.org/

I believe that this technology has been incorporated into the Eclipse Provisioning System P2 to solve plugin dependencies. http://blog.mancoosi.org/index.php/2008/06/01/4-edos-offspring-1-eclipse-p2-will-include-sat-solver-technology-for-managing-plugins